# Spring breaks Selenium dependencies

Tags: spring, selenium, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to use Selenium with Spring.

If I use Selenium without Spring, everything just works fine. Whenever I add the Spring dependencies (without Spring code), the following exception is thrown on execution:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
>
> ...

This is the main part of my maven file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jadira.usertype/usertype.core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-htmlunit-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.29.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>com.opera</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-exec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--&lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava &ndash;&gt;-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>24.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
            <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
        <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

And this is the maven dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.27:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.27:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.15.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.2.15.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.6.14:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.196:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901-1.jdbc4:compile
[INFO] +- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:jar:6.0.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.spi:jar:6.0.1.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:2.53.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:2.53.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:jar:2.53.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:2.53.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-opera-driver:jar:3.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:2.53.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:2.53.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.5.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:2.53.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.13.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:3.11.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:jar:2.29.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.21:compile
[INFO] |     +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.17:compile
[INFO] |     +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:neko-htmlunit:jar:2.21:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |     +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.18:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] |           \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:24.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
```

Update: These is my code - very simple, but the firefoxdriver can't even be created..

```
public class Application {

    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // exception thrown here

        driver.close();
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

By looking at the dependencies of Selenium in the [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium), I could see which versions were needed for Selenium to run. Then explicitly adding these jars in maven could solve the dependency conflict.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your code trials please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The versions of `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver` and `net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit` should be aligned, but you're using 2.29 of the former and 2.21 of the latter. If you remove the versions from your dependency declarations, Spring Boot's dependency management will take care of things for you.

Comment: Thanks, removing the versions did it. Instead of just giving me the fish, could you teach me fishing, pls?
Why does Spring take care about the resolution and not maven itself?

Comment: Unfortunately the selenium-firefox-driver needs the specific version 3.11.0 to be compatible with my firefox. Is there a proper way to tackle this? :)

Comment: Why des Spring actually mess it up? Without Spring it works perfectly. What is Spring doing wrong and how can I correct it (manually)? :)

Comment: Spring isn't doing anything wrong. It provides dependency management (which you have chosen to use by using `spring-boot-starter-parent`) that keeps dependency versions in sync. You've partially overridden this dependency management by adding versions to some of your dependency declarations. The correct way to override that dependency management is [described](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-parent-pom) in the documentation.

Comment: Since October 30, 2021 there is also the to-the-point article "[Overriding Spring Boot Managed Dependency Versions](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-override-dependency-versions)" (Baeldung).